# Properties file not loading in Spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to load properties using annotations:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
```

and

```
@Value("${my.property}")
String myProperty;
```

as a result, myProperty is always null

While it is working using:

```
BatchConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
```

This is my Batch conf class signature :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;
...

}
```

And Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
}
```

I also tried to load it using:

```
    @Autowired
    public static Environment env;
```

But env is also null.

Comment: can you share location of your properties file?

Comment: Spring Boot already loads the `application.properties` no need to manually try to load it again. You cannot inject into `static` variables.

Comment: I removed `static` and `@PropertySource`, still not working

Comment: You don't need `@PropertySource` as Spring Boot already loads that file. If it is `null` it is because you are creating an instance yourself of that class yourself. If Spring would do it your application would fail to start as it couldn't resolve the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass following JVM Argument when running Spring boot application

```
--spring.config.location=properties file path
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove {} in your @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
It should be

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

or

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
```

Comment: [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html#value--) attribute of `@PropertySource` is a `String[]` so having `{}` is valid.

Comment: Yes @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, you are right of course. Although I would use PropertySources or just repeatable annotations, the {} is indeed valid